# Making a misnamed selector generate a compile time error

Tags: objective-c

In objective-c how can I make a misnamed selector generate a compile time error?

For example, say I have this

```
 @selector(some_misnamed_func)
```

And my class has this member

```
  -(void)some_func
```

I want the objective-c compiler to tell me that it can't find that function at compile time rather than generate a run-time exception only when that code is run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compile your code with `-Wundeclared-selector`, or *Undeclared selector* in Xcode’s build settings. Since that’s a warning only, you can couple it with `-Werror` (resp. *Treat Warnings as Errors* in Xcode) to make that warning (and all other warnings) behave as an error and effectively abort the compilation.

Comment: +1 Interesting. But that would be disregarding the dynamic nature of Objective-C, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not really;  as long as the selector is declared *somewhere*, it is OK.  Given the taint of the C type system on arguments/return-value, trying to dynamically call untyped generic selectors is a world of pain anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler can warn you if there’s no such selector in visible files. And if you turn on treating warnings as errors, you’ll get a nice error. The catch is that if you mistake the right selector for some other existing selector (even on a completely different class), the compiler will not say a thing. This is due to [late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding), the compiler can’t know all messages a class will respond to in runtime.

Comment: thanks - accepted Bavarious's response as the answer but +1'ed yours to because it was also good.